# Using dollar sign vs brackets for use inside user-defined function?

Tags: r, indexing

I've transitioned into writing some user-defined functions in R, but I'm hung up on whether it's best to use a dollar sign or bracket when indexing several data_frame columns.  My function is like this, for a conditional value replace:

```
replacer <- function(df_col1,df_col2 i, k) {
  df_col1[df_col2 %in% i] <-k
}
```

Is there a better way to write this, one that has fewer arguments? With four arguments my way isn't very practical.

Comment: Base R has a replace function, it would look something like `replace(df_col1, df_col2 %in% i, k)` for your example.

Comment: It's best to use brackets if you're passing names.

Comment: @RichScriven, how so? Thanks.

Comment: @elliot see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329036/how-to-reference-columns-of-a-data-frame-within-a-data-frame) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-vector-of-column-names) for some ideas.  Most likely better SO posts exist as this is a fairly common question.

Comment: You are missing a comma after `df_col2` in `function(df_col1,df_col2 i, k)`.