# Stack IDs instead of variable/value in R

Tags: r

If I have data from:

```
df <- data.frame(x=sample(letters[1:20], replace=T),
 y=sample(letters[1:20], replace=T), z=sample(1:10, replace=T))
```

and I want to stack the x and y 'id' columns, and thus repeat the value, how would I do that?

So, pretend the first row of the data frame is

```
   x y  z
1  p r  5
```

I want the first row in a reshaped data frame to look like:

```
   id value
1  p  5
2  r  5
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181060/reshaping-time-series-data-from-wide-to-tall-format-for-plotting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df),measure.vars = 1:2)
```

Comment: ah ok, should have just played with melt more. Weird to me to set the 'result' column as the id.