# Calculating monthly returns in long format

Tags: r, reshape, finance, quantmod, tidyr

I have daily closing prices data set in long format and I want to calculate monthly returns(arithmetic). It is calculated as

> (m1-m0)/m0

Where m1 and m0 are prices on the last days of current and last month respectively.This is a sample of two stocks:

```
dput(q1) 
structure(list(Date = structure(c(13027, 13028, 13031, 13032,
13034, 13035, 13038, 13039, 13040, 13041, 13042, 13045, 13046,  13047,
13048, 13049, 13052, 13053, 13054, 13055, 13056, 13059,  13060, 13061,
13062, 13063, 13066, 13067, 13069, 13070, 13073,  13074, 13075, 13076,
13077, 13080, 13081, 13082, 13083, 13084,  13087, 13088, 13089, 13094,
13095, 13096, 13097, 13098, 13101,  13103, 13104, 13105, 13108, 13109,
13110, 13111, 13112, 13113,  13115, 13116, 13117, 13118, 13119, 13122,
13123, 13124, 13125,  13126, 13129, 13130, 13131, 13132, 13133, 13136,
13137, 13138,  13139, 13140, 13143, 13144, 13145, 13146, 13147, 13150,
13151,  13152, 13153, 13154, 13157, 13158, 13160, 13161, 13164, 13165,
13166, 13167, 13168, 13171, 13172, 13173, 13175, 13178, 13179,  13180,
13181, 13182, 13185, 13186, 13187, 13189, 13192, 13193,  13194, 13195,
13196, 13199, 13200, 13201, 13202, 13203, 13206,  13207, 13208, 13209,
13210, 13213, 13214, 13215, 13216, 13217,  13220, 13221, 13223, 13224,
13227, 13228, 13229, 13230, 13231,  13234, 13235, 13236, 13237, 13238,
13241, 13242, 13243, 13245,  13248, 13250, 13251, 13255, 13256, 13257,
13258, 13259, 13262,  13263, 13264, 13265, 13266, 13267, 13270, 13271,
13272, 13273,  13276, 13277, 13278, 13279, 13280, 13283, 13284, 13285,
13286,  13287, 13290, 13291, 13292, 13293, 13294, 13297, 13298, 13299,
13300, 13301, 13304, 13305, 13306, 13307, 13308, 13311, 13312,  13313,
13314, 13315, 13318, 13319, 13320, 13321, 13322, 13324,  13325, 13326,
13327, 13328, 13329, 13332, 13333, 13334, 13335,  13336, 13339, 13340,
13341, 13342, 13343, 13346, 13347, 13348,  13349, 13350, 13353, 13354,
13355, 13356, 13357, 13360, 13361,  13362, 13363, 13364, 13367, 13368,
13369, 13370, 13371, 13374,  13376, 13377, 13378, 13381, 13382, 13383,
13384, 13385, 13388,  13389, 13390, 13391, 13027, 13028, 13031, 13032,
13034, 13035,  13038, 13039, 13040, 13041, 13042, 13045, 13046, 13047,
13048,  13049, 13052, 13053, 13054, 13055, 13056, 13059, 13060, 13061,
13062, 13063, 13066, 13067, 13069, 13070, 13073, 13074, 13075,  13076,
13077, 13080, 13081, 13082, 13083, 13084, 13087, 13088,  13089, 13094,
13095, 13096, 13097, 13098, 13101, 13103, 13104,  13105, 13108, 13109,
13110, 13111, 13112, 13113, 13115, 13116,  13117, 13118, 13119, 13122,
13123, 13124, 13125, 13126, 13129,  13130, 13131, 13132, 13133, 13136,
13137, 13138, 13139, 13140,  13143, 13144, 13145, 13146, 13147, 13150,
13151, 13152, 13153,  13154, 13157, 13158, 13160, 13161, 13164, 13165,
13166, 13167,  13168, 13171, 13172, 13173, 13175, 13178, 13179, 13180,
13181,  13182, 13185, 13186, 13187, 13189, 13192, 13193, 13194, 13195,
13196, 13199, 13200, 13201, 13202, 13203, 13206, 13207, 13208,  13209,
13210, 13213, 13214, 13215, 13216, 13217, 13220, 13221,  13223, 13224,
13227, 13228, 13229, 13230, 13231, 13234, 13235,  13236, 13237, 13238,
13241, 13242, 13243, 13245, 13248, 13250,  13251, 13255, 13256, 13257,
13258, 13259, 13262, 13263, 13264,  13265, 13266, 13267, 13270, 13271,
13272, 13273, 13276, 13277,  13278, 13279, 13280, 13283, 13284, 13285,
13286, 13287, 13290,  13291, 13292, 13293, 13294, 13297, 13298, 13299,
13300, 13301,  13304, 13305, 13306, 13307, 13308, 13311, 13312, 13313,
13314,  13315, 13318, 13319, 13320, 13321, 13322, 13324, 13325, 13326,
13327, 13328, 13329, 13332, 13333, 13334, 13335, 13336, 13339,  13340,
13341, 13342, 13343, 13346, 13347, 13348, 13349, 13350,  13353, 13354,
13355, 13356, 13357, 13360, 13361, 13362, 13363,  13364, 13367, 13368,
13369, 13370, 13371, 13374, 13376, 13377,  13378, 13381, 13382, 13383,
13384, 13385, 13388, 13389, 13390,  13391), class = "Date"), Firm =
c("ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",  "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",  "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE", "ADE", "ADE",  "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE", "ADE",  "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE",  "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",  "ADE",
"ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",  "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",  "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",  "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",  "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",  "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE", "ADE", "ADE",  "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE", "ADE",  "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE",  "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",  "ADE",
"ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",  "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",  "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",  "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",  "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",  "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE", "ADE", "ADE",  "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE", "ADE",  "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE",  "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",  "ADE",
"ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE", "ADE",  "ADE", "ADE",
"ADE", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",  "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",  "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",  "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",  "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP", "AJP", "AJP",  "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP", "AJP",  "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP",  "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",  "AJP",
"AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",  "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",  "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",  "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",  "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",  "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP", "AJP", "AJP",  "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP", "AJP",  "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP",  "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",  "AJP",
"AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",  "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",  "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",  "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",  "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",  "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP", "AJP", "AJP",  "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP", "AJP",  "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP",  "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP", "AJP",
"AJP"), Price = c(7.05, 6.81, 6.98, 6.82, 6.81, 6.75, 6.73, 6.71, 
6.6, 6.62, 6.71, 7.01, 6.82, 6.59, 6.25, 6.29, 6.48, 6.43, 6.45, 
6.39, 6.3, 6.39, 6.61, 6.62, 6.52, 6.48, 6.39, 6.31, 6.31, 6.21, 
6.15, 6.14, 6.02, 5.88, 5.91, 5.91, 5.91, 5.95, 5.84, 5.73, 5.83, 
5.95, 5.94, 6.01, 6.05, 5.95, 5.94, 6.02, 6.06, 6.1, 6.52, 6.42, 
6.36, 6.27, 6.29, 6.26, 6.26, 6.28, 6.41, 6.46, 6.34, 6.34, 6.27, 
6.38, 6.46, 6.37, 6.34, 6.38, 6.39, 6.33, 6.31, 6.22, 6.23, 6.28, 
6.27, 6.18, 6.17, 6.09, 5.99, 6.1, 6.01, 6, 5.9, 5.99, 6.06, 
6.1, 6.05, 6.1, 6.11, 6.05, 6.05, 6.03, 6, 6, 6.01, 6.07, 6.14, 
6.02, 6.06, 6.01, 6.01, 6.03, 6, 5.98, 5.81, 5.78, 5.95, 5.86, 
5.77, 5.78, 5.81, 5.8, 5.8, 6, 5.8, 5.75, 5.79, 5.81, 5.75, 5.75, 
5.76, 5.76, 5.79, 5.77, 5.74, 5.71, 5.63, 5.66, 5.69, 5.65, 5.63, 
5.61, 5.58, 5.58, 5.63, 5.58, 5.52, 5.53, 5.76, 5.96, 5.85, 5.94, 
5.88, 5.99, 6.43, 6.38, 6.37, 6.41, 6.31, 6.11, 5.93, 6.02, 6.11, 
6.07, 6.08, 6.02, 5.99, 6, 6.06, 6.02, 5.98, 6.07, 7.29, 8.75, 
10.5, 11.55, 12.53, 12.69, 13.96, 15.36, 16.13, 16.94, 17.66, 
18.55, 18.97, 18.18, 17.28, 16.42, 15.6, 14.88, 15.62, 16.41, 
17.23, 18.09, 19, 18.47, 17.55, 16.68, 15.85, 15.06, 14.3, 13.59, 
12.91, 12.27, 11.66, 12.16, 12.77, 13.41, 14.08, 13.56, 13.67, 
13.86, 13.17, 12.62, 12.45, 12.47, 13, 12.51, 12.36, 12.55, 12.47, 
12.06, 11.77, 11.81, 12.19, 12.32, 12.03, 11.62, 11.43, 11.05, 
11.18, 10.72, 10.74, 10.53, 10.84, 11.39, 11.53, 11.51, 11.24, 
11.36, 11.62, 11.53, 11.45, 11.73, 11.81, 12.96, 13.36, 13.57, 
14.09, 13.41, 13.1, 12.72, 12.52, 12.26, 12, 12.18, 12.52, 12.48, 
12.2, 12, 13.54, 13.97, 13.67, 13.32, 13.24, 12.79, 12.98, 12.73, 
12.45, 12.69, 12.71, 12.61, 12.34, 11.95, 11.36, 11.11, 11.67, 
11.57, 11.61, 11.31, 11.25, 11.24, 11.44, 11.43, 11.21, 11.25, 
10.95, 10.63, 10.59, 10.38, 9.86, 9.91, 9.09, 9.16, 9.17, 9.16, 
9.14, 9.14, 8.96, 8.66, 8.71, 8.86, 8.84, 9.19, 9.46, 9.31, 9.49, 
9.73, 10.71, 11.03, 10.76, 10.73, 10.99, 10.84, 10.81, 10.94, 
10.83, 10.76, 10.61, 10.51, 11.13, 10.91, 10.67, 10.59, 10.68, 
10.62, 10.81, 10.83, 11.03, 11.06, 10.67, 10.59, 10.46, 10.55, 
10.35, 10.41, 10.63, 10.54, 10.23, 10.14, 10.14, 10.2, 10.4, 
10.67, 10.79, 10.97, 10.8, 10.96, 11.4, 11.27, 11.17, 11.81, 
12.07, 11.3, 11.16, 11.53, 11.31, 11.23, 11.24, 11.06, 11.67, 
11.49, 11.23, 10.91, 10.81, 10.81, 10.84, 10.61, 10.68, 10.75, 
11.08, 11.07, 10.78, 10.79, 10.58, 10.48, 10.46, 10.33, 10.35, 
10.31, 10.3, 10.09, 10.1, 9.91, 9.86, 9.9, 9.76, 9.83, 9.58, 
9.61, 9.73, 9.59, 9.48, 9.16, 9.03, 8.95, 9.12, 9.08, 9.02, 9.11, 
8.79, 8.67, 9.14, 9.75, 10.3, 10.19, 10.35, 9.93, 9.98, 9.85, 
9.61, 9.66, 9.71, 9.71, 9.93, 9.81, 9.99, 9.77, 9.69, 9.81, 10.71, 
12.85, 12.76, 12.26, 11.94, 12.51, 12.22, 12.23, 12.32, 11.79, 
11.75, 10.94, 11.09, 11.53, 10.7, 10.3, 9.58, 9.96, 9.9, 9.75, 
10.01, 10.13, 10.05, 9.61, 9.4, 9.04, 9.03, 8.77, 7.89, 7.35, 
8.23, 8.2, 8.05, 8.07, 8.35, 8.7, 9.16, 9.24, 9.37, 9.4, 9.7, 
9.66, 9.37, 9.07, 9.35, 9.52, 9.42, 9.64, 9.47, 9.51, 9.36, 9.06, 
10.49, 10.24, 9.85, 9.93, 9.7, 9.43, 9.57, 9.33, 9.6, 9.43, 9.63, 
9.72, 9.83, 9.69, 9.78, 9.44, 9.39, 9.27, 9.35, 9.21, 9.19, 9.3, 
9.45, 9.73, 10.61, 10.82, 10.62, 10.27, 10.41, 10.31, 10.46, 
10.21, 10.02, 10.24, 10.13, 10.09, 10.07, 9.94)), .Names = c("Date",  "Firm", "Price"), row.names = c(NA, -500L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I don't know how to do this in long format so I converted it into wide format and got the month end prices

```
q<-  spread(q1,Firm,Price)  q$Date<-as.Date(q$Date)  rownames(q) = q[[1]]  q<-as.xts(q)  q.m.r<-q[ endpoints(q, on="months", k=1), ]
```

I also had issues with `monthlyReturn` function from quantmod so I will calculate returns in long format. I also need the data into the long format for further processing. So, used gather() function from tidyr but it did not work

```
Error in UseMethod("gather_") : no applicable method for 'gather_' applied to an object of class "c('xts', 'zoo')"
```

I also found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/manipulatr/lnqN3y7-ysE) but I don't know what to put after Price

```
xts2df <- function(x) {data.frame(date=index(x), coredata(x))}  g<-gather(xts2df(q.m.r), Firm, Price, ?)
```

I also went through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181060/reshaping-time-series-data-from-wide-to-tall-format-for-plotting) and applied

```
m <- melt(q.m.r,id="Date",variable_name="Firm")  names(m) <- sub("value","Price",names(m))
```

But it does not stack the columns. Thank you for reading and kindly help me to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xts` `endpoints` function can be used with either base R or `dplyr` to compute the monthly returns.  The two versions are:

```
# Use xts and base R
  library(xts)
  q2 <- within(q1[endpoints(q1$Date, on="months"),], 
               Return <- ave(Price, Firm, FUN=function(x) c(NA, (diff(x)/head(x,-1)))))[,c("Date", "Firm", "Return")]
  q2 <- na.omit(q2)


# Use xts and dplyr
  library(dplyr)
  library(xts)
  q3 <- q1[endpoints(q1$Date, on="months"),] %>%
                             group_by(Firm) %>%
                             transmute(Date=Date, Return = c(NA, (diff(Price)/head(Price,-1)))) %>%
                             na.omit()
```

Comment: thank you. I have checked the returns in excel and it matches with the ones in the q2 and its fine. But WHY the prices are there in Index series and value cloumns? Please make it returns only. Thanks again

Comment: I've posted simpler versions which don't include the prices in the results.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I need. Just to learn: why was arithmetic=FALSE in diff function?.

Comment: The earlier version had an `xts` time series object as the argument for `diff` so that the function `diff.xts` was actually used.  If `arithmetic = FALSE` in `diff.xts`, the geometric difference, `x[i]/x[i-1]`, is calculated. The financial return is then just  `geometric difference - 1`.  The base R `diff` function doesn't have this feature so the code has to explicitly divide the `diff` result,`x[i]- x[i-1]`,  by `x[i-1]` to calculate the financial return..