# R: convert a list of variables by date to a data frame with two columns for variable and date

Tags: r

I have a list of dates and temperatures,

```
    2016-03-28 2016-03-29 2016-03-22 2016-04-14 2016-04-25 2016-03-30 2016-04-10 
    45.6692    48.7166    49.9586    54.3002    55.4288    56.1650    57.3332
```

that I would like to convert to a dataframe with two columns:

```
          date     temp
    2016-03-28  45.6692
    2016-03-29  48.7166
    2016-03-22  49.9586
```

and so on.  Let me know if I can provide any further information. Thanks.

Comment: What is your input, a file, an R object: dataframe, vector? Please provide  [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This post might be [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181060).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a vector like `v`

```
v <- rnorm(10,50,3) 
names(v) <- as.Date(1:10,origin="2016-10-21")
```

Then I would just extract names in one column and values in another:

```
data.frame(temp=unname(v),date=names(v))
```

Comment: is there a way to remove the date at the beginning of the temp column? Thanks.