# All possible qplots with different categorical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, data-visualization

I've made a plot of variables lsiete and lcinco with the following code:

```
qplot(lsiete, lcinco, data=enc, color=LENGTHE)
```

[image]

However, I also want to give colour to the scatter plot by the following factor variables to visualize it all at the same time:

```
> names(enc[,ind])
 [1] "SEX"      "RACE"     "MSTATUS"  "EDUC"     "POSITION" "SATSCHED" "TYPESCH"  "FLEX"     "URBRUR"   "HOURS"   
[11] "SCHOOL"   "ANJOB"    "TYPERES"  "LENGTHE"  "HOWLONG"  "REASONQ"  "REASONW"  "WHY"
```

So, I want a panel with all the possible scatter plots with the mentioned condition.

How Can I write the code to do that?

EDIT: To be more clear, `lsiete` and `lcinco` doesnt change, instead the variables in color change

EDIT 2: To give a reproducible example. I create the following data frame with random data:

```
sn <- data.frame(a=rnorm(100),b=rnorm(100), cat1=sample(c('male', 'female'), 100, replace=TRUE),cat2=sample(c('U', 'AL'), 100, replace=TRUE),cat3=sample(c('AR', 'ML'), 100, replace=TRUE),cat4=sample(c('LM', 'KR'), 100, replace=TRUE))
```

I can create a qplot with a and b, and give colour according to cat2:

```
qplot(a,b,data=sn,color=cat2)
```

But, I want to keep a and b always, and give colour according the rest of categorical variables to have a panel of all possible scatterplots.

---

Comment: We need to prepare the data for ggplot by converting it to from wide to long. See [this post for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181060), then plot. Also, it would be nice to give us a [toy example data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to reshape your data and use facetting. This will create a single plot with four panels and a shared legend.

```
sn2 <- tidyr::gather(sn, 'cat', 'col', cat1:cat1.1)

ggplot(sn2, aes(a, b, col = col)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~cat)
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you would prefer separate legends you'll need to create four plots and stitch them together, like so:

```
plot_fun <- function(cat) {
  ggplot(sn, aes_(~a, ~b, col = cat)) + geom_point()
}

plot_list <- lapply(c(~cat1, ~cat2, ~cat3, ~cat1.1), plot_fun)
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = plot_list, align = 'hv')
```

[image]

Comment: Your second code is nice but I have problems with categorical variables because in real data there are a lot of categorical variables and I don't know how to set the string I created as parameter. For example, I created: this categories:
 [1] "~SEX"      "~RACE"     "~MSTATUS"  "~EDUC"     "~POSITION" "~SATSCHED" "~TYPESCH"  "~FLEX"     "~URBRUR"  
[10] "~HOURS"    "~SCHOOL"   "~ANJOB"    "~TYPERES"  "~LENGTHE"  "~HOWLONG"  "~REASONQ"  "~REASONW"  "~WHY"  , but this characters are not recognized like categorical variables in ggplot. How Can I fix that?

Comment: I can't really tell, since my code works on your example data. Are those variables factors or character vectors in you data.frame? Or are they numeric? What output do you get?

Comment: They are factor variables, the problem is in lapply(c(~cat1, ~cat2, ~cat3, ~cat1.1), plot_fun), I can't write manually more than 100 hundred factor variables like that.

Comment: Replace `aes_(~a, ~b, col = cat)` with `aes_string('a', 'b', col = cat)` and use `names(data)` to get your names.